# PyTorch Object Detection with GPU on Ubuntu 18.04 - RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate xx.xx MiB

Tags: gpu, pytorch

I'm attempting to get this PyTorch person detection example:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

running locally with a GPU, either in a Jupyter Notebook or a regular python file.  I get the error in the title either way.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.  Here is a summary of the steps I've performed:

1) Stock Ubuntu 18.04 install on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen 2 with a GTX 1650 GPU.

2) Perform a standard CUDA 10.0 / cuDNN 7.4 install.  I'd rather not restate all the steps as this post is going to be more than long enough already.  This is a standard procedure, pretty much any link found via googling is what I followed.

3) Install `torch` and `torchvision`

```
pip3 install torch torchvision
```

4) From this link on the PyTorch site:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

I've both saved the linked notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/vision/blob/temp-tutorial/tutorials/torchvision_finetuning_instance_segmentation.ipynb

And Also tried the link at the bottom that has the regular Python file:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/_static/tv-training-code.py

5) Before running either the notebook or the regular Python way, I did the following (found at the top of the above linked notebook):

Install the CoCo API into Python:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git
cd cocoapi/PythonAPI
```

open Makefile in gedit, change the two instances of "python" to "python3", then:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Get the necessary files the above linked files need to run:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/vision.git
cd vision
git checkout v0.5.0
```

from `~/vision/references/detection`, copy `coco_eval.py`, `coco_utils.py`, `engine.py`, `transforms.py`, and `utils.py` to whichever directory the above linked notebook or `tv-training-code.py` file are being ran from.

6) Download the Penn Fudan Pedestrian dataset from the link on the above page:

https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jshi/ped_html/PennFudanPed.zip

then unzip and put in the same directory as the notebook or `tv-training-code.py`

In case the above link ever breaks or just for easier reference, here is `tv-training-code.py` as I have downloaded it at this time:

```
# Sample code from the TorchVision 0.3 Object Detection Finetuning Tutorial
# http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

import os
import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image

import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor
from torchvision.models.detection.mask_rcnn import MaskRCNNPredictor

from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate
import utils
import transforms as T


class PennFudanDataset(object):
    def __init__(self, root, transforms):
        self.root = root
        self.transforms = transforms
        # load all image files, sorting them to
        # ensure that they are aligned
        self.imgs = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "PNGImages"))))
        self.masks = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "PedMasks"))))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # load images ad masks
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root, "PNGImages", self.imgs[idx])
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.root, "PedMasks", self.masks[idx])
        img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
        # note that we haven't converted the mask to RGB,
        # because each color corresponds to a different instance
        # with 0 being background
        mask = Image.open(mask_path)

        mask = np.array(mask)
        # instances are encoded as different colors
        obj_ids = np.unique(mask)
        # first id is the background, so remove it
        obj_ids = obj_ids[1:]

        # split the color-encoded mask into a set
        # of binary masks
        masks = mask == obj_ids[:, None, None]

        # get bounding box coordinates for each mask
        num_objs = len(obj_ids)
        boxes = []
        for i in range(num_objs):
            pos = np.where(masks[i])
            xmin = np.min(pos[1])
            xmax = np.max(pos[1])
            ymin = np.min(pos[0])
            ymax = np.max(pos[0])
            boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

        boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
        # there is only one class
        labels = torch.ones((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)
        masks = torch.as_tensor(masks, dtype=torch.uint8)

        image_id = torch.tensor([idx])
        area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
        # suppose all instances are not crowd
        iscrowd = torch.zeros((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)

        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = labels
        target["masks"] = masks
        target["image_id"] = image_id
        target["area"] = area
        target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd

        if self.transforms is not None:
            img, target = self.transforms(img, target)

        return img, target

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.imgs)

def get_model_instance_segmentation(num_classes):
    # load an instance segmentation model pre-trained pre-trained on COCO
    model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

    # get number of input features for the classifier
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # replace the pre-trained head with a new one
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)

    # now get the number of input features for the mask classifier
    in_features_mask = model.roi_heads.mask_predictor.conv5_mask.in_channels
    hidden_layer = 256
    # and replace the mask predictor with a new one
    model.roi_heads.mask_predictor = MaskRCNNPredictor(in_features_mask,
                                                       hidden_layer,
                                                       num_classes)

    return model


def get_transform(train):
    transforms = []
    transforms.append(T.ToTensor())
    if train:
        transforms.append(T.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5))
    return T.Compose(transforms)


def main():
    # train on the GPU or on the CPU, if a GPU is not available
    device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

    # our dataset has two classes only - background and person
    num_classes = 2
    # use our dataset and defined transformations
    dataset = PennFudanDataset('PennFudanPed', get_transform(train=True))
    dataset_test = PennFudanDataset('PennFudanPed', get_transform(train=False))

    # split the dataset in train and test set
    indices = torch.randperm(len(dataset)).tolist()
    dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, indices[:-50])
    dataset_test = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset_test, indices[-50:])

    # define training and validation data loaders
    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4,
        collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

    data_loader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset_test, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=4,
        collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

    # get the model using our helper function
    model = get_model_instance_segmentation(num_classes)

    # move model to the right device
    model.to(device)

    # construct an optimizer
    params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.005,
                                momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
    # and a learning rate scheduler
    lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                                   step_size=3,
                                                   gamma=0.1)

    # let's train it for 10 epochs
    num_epochs = 10

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
        train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
        # update the learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step()
        # evaluate on the test dataset
        evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)

    print("That's it!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is an exmaple run of `tv-training-code.py`

```
$ python3 tv-training-code.py 
Epoch: [0]  [ 0/60]  eta: 0:01:17  lr: 0.000090  loss: 4.1717 (4.1717)  loss_classifier: 0.8903 (0.8903)  loss_box_reg: 0.1379 (0.1379)  loss_mask: 3.0632 (3.0632)  loss_objectness: 0.0700 (0.0700)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0104 (0.0104)  time: 1.2864  data: 0.1173  max mem: 1865
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tv-training-code.py", line 165, in <module>
    main()
  File "tv-training-code.py", line 156, in main
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
  File "/xxx/PennFudanExample/engine.py", line 46, in train_one_epoch
    losses.backward()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 166, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 99, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 77, in apply
    return self._forward_cls.backward(self, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 189, in wrapper
    outputs = fn(ctx, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/ops/roi_align.py", line 38, in backward
    output_size[0], output_size[1], bs, ch, h, w, sampling_ratio)
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 132.00 MiB (GPU 0; 3.81 GiB total capacity; 2.36 GiB already allocated; 132.69 MiB free; 310.59 MiB cached) (malloc at /pytorch/c10/cuda/CUDACachingAllocator.cpp:267)
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string const&) + 0x33 (0x7fdfb6c9b813 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: <unknown function> + 0x1ce68 (0x7fdfb6edce68 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so)
frame #2: <unknown function> + 0x1de6e (0x7fdfb6edde6e in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so)
frame #3: at::native::empty_cuda(c10::ArrayRef<long>, c10::TensorOptions const&, c10::optional<c10::MemoryFormat>) + 0x279 (0x7fdf59472789 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[many more frame lines omitted]
```

Clearly the line:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 132.00 MiB (GPU 0; 3.81 GiB total capacity; 2.36 GiB already allocated; 132.69 MiB free; 310.59 MiB cached) (malloc at /pytorch/c10/cuda/CUDACachingAllocator.cpp:267)
```

is the critical error.

If I run an nvidia-smi before a run:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Dec 24 14:32:49 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.44       Driver Version: 440.44       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     5W /  N/A |    296MiB /  3903MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1190      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           142MiB |
|    0      1830      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          72MiB |
|    0      3711      G   ...uest-channel-token=14371934934688572948    78MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It seems pretty clear there is plenty of GPU memory available (this GPU is 4GB).

Moreover, I'm confident my CUDA/cuDNN install and GPU hardware are good b/c I train and inference the TensorFlow object detection API on this computer frequently, and as long as I use the `allow_growth` option I never have GPU related errors.

From Googling on this error it seems to be relatively common.  The most common solutions are:

1) Try a smaller batch size (not really applicable in this case since the training and testing batch sizes are 2 and 1 respectively, and I tried with 1 and 1 and still got the same error)

2) Update to the latest version of PyTorch (but I'm already at the latest version).

Some other suggestions involve reworking the training script.  I'm very familiar with TensorFlow but I'm new to PyTorch so I'm not sure how to go about that.  Also, most of the rework suggestions I can find for this error do not pertain to object detection and therefore I'm not able to relate them to this training script specifically.

Has anybody else gotten this script to run locally with an NVIDIA GPU?  Do you suspect a OS/CUDA/PyTorch configuration concern, or is there someway the script can be reworked to prevent this error?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange, after changing both the training and testing batch size to 1, it now does not crash with a GPU error.  Very strange since I'm certain I tried this before.

Perhaps it had something to do with changing the batch size to 1 for both training and testing, and then rebooting or somehow refreshing something else?  I'm not really sure.  Very odd.

Now the `evaluate` function call is crashing with the error:

```
object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

But it seems this is completely unrelated so I'll make a separate post for that.